# .NET assembly DLL missing dependencies

Tags: .net, c++-cli, assemblies

I'm making a C++/CLI wrapper for a C++ class, but the DLL created by building my C++/CLI project fails to load in C#, Assembly.Load throws a fileNotFound exception with the message "Could not load file or assembly 'CLIExport.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

The C++/CLI project includes only the wrapper class, the C++ class, and one header file that the C++ class depends on, for which the source and header files has been added to the solution, no references have been added. Do I need to add references to the C++ class in the C++/CLI project? I don't know what the C# app thinks the assembly is missing, and I don't know what I need to add references to, does the C++/CLI project need to have a reference to every .net type it uses like classes in the System namespace?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to load an x86 lib into a 64bit project ?

Comment: I don't believe so, I made the C++/CLI project on the same machine as the C# project I'm testing it in, on a 64 bit PC. Can you create x86 libs on a 64 bit machine?

Comment: Use http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and open the wrapper DLL and see if there any dependencies missing.

Comment: using dependency walker I get an error when I try to open the DLL.

"Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module."

It says IESHIMS.dll is missing

Comment: After locating IESHIMS.dll and loading the dll in dependency walker again I get the following error. "Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module."

Comment: I wouldn't worry about IESHIMS.dll I don't think that is the cause of your problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Targetting x86 vs AnyCPU when building for 64 bit window OSes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947264/targetting-x86-vs-anycpu-when-building-for-64-bit-window-oses)

Comment: Dependency Walker let me know that I needed to have `Ijwhost.dll` right next to my C++/CLI dll otherwise I get this game error from `AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyPath()`.

Comment: Er "same" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to use unmanaged `x86` dlls in a 64bit solution.

Try doing : Right click on your solution, then `Configuration manager`, and set all your projects to `x86`, then try building again.

Im pretty sure that your build configuration is inconsistent, therefore the error message (I ran into the same problem a few times ...)

You can read up here : [What does the Visual Studio "Any CPU" target mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/visual-studio-any-cpu-target)

And a quick overview of the different targets in VS : http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/

Comment: I only have one project in my solution, I've just added the C++ source files to this solution, is that incorrect? Should I have added the whole C++ project to the solution? In the confiruration manager there is no x64/x86 option, I can only change build config(debug/release), Platform(win32 is the only option) and a checkbox marked 'build'

Comment: Can you not create a new Configuration for your project ?

Comment: @BillWalton Surely you have two projects? The project that contains the C++ Class and the C++/CLI wrapper class and then the C# project that consumes the DLL produced by the other project?

Comment: That's what I dont understand Alastair, how can you do a C# wrapper for a C++ project, with only one C++/CLI project in your solution ?

Comment: Sorry I had a C# project in a different place to which I'd given the DLL produced by the C++/CLI project, but theyre not in the same solution.

Comment: I maintain, you probably have a target problem.

Comment: @BillWalton If you open the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" - you will find this in the "Visual Studio Tools" folder in the Start Menu folder for Visual Studio. 

Then navigate to the directory where the wrapper DLL is and type:

CorFlags.exe yourWrapperdll.dll

and report back what it says

Comment: You were correct it is an x86 DLL, when I create a new configuration however the only option in the active solution platform dialogue is 'win32', no x86 or x64, and if I create a new active solution platform, the only option in the 'copy setting from' dropdown is win32.